# Некорректно отображается TextView без вызова setLayoutParams

Tags: android, android-textview

Я создаю `TextView` в Java-коде и присваиваю ему стиль следующим образом:

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.myStyle), null, 0);
```

Вот XML-код стиля:

```
<style name="myStyle">

    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>

</style>
```

Но `TextView` в компоновке отображается некорректно. Я попробовал добавить эту команду в Java-код:

```
mTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
```

и только тогда элемент стал правильно отображаться. В чём заключается такая потребность вызывать этот метод `setLayoutParams`, если я уже указал значение параметров `android:layout_height`, `android:layout_weight` и `android:layout_width` в стиле? То есть, мой вопрос заключается в том, почему без вызова в Java-коде метода `setLayoutParams` элементу не присваиваются значения `android:layout_height`, `android:layout_weight` и `android:layout_width` из стиля и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не очень хорошо делать при динамическом создании View изначально, старайтесь при динамической верстки все параметр использовать в коде, а стили выносить в отдельные классы, те создавать ваш StyleWrapper, иначе в вашем коде нет смысла не по производительности, не по структуре. Вы будуте дольше искать ошибки верстки постояно изучая несколько участков в коде. Хотя на практике есть примеры полностью динамической верстки больших приложений (telegram), и даже есть либы для упрощения. Не суть. Что касается ответа. Он прост.

Никак setLayoutParams в вашем случае, не влияют на отображения вью если вы добавляете ваше View parent которого является LinearLayout.

Вы прочитайте что такое ContextWrapper и для чего он необходим, уж точно не для того чтобы для всех View выставлять параметры, weight или gravity которые в большинстве случае не будут применены.

у TextView применения стиля делается примерно так:

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, R.style.myStyle)
```

для того чтобы вью добавить в любой parent необходимо сделать примерно так:

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(this); //создать
    textView.setText("всё хорошо"); //присвоить значение
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(textView); // добавить View
```

Если вы хотите данный View расположить определным образом у парента только тогда применяюстя LayoutParams, в зависимости какой парент у вас, это очень важно!

```
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1)); //только сейчас вы выставляете вес = 1
mainLayout.addView(textView) // добавить View
```

Исходя из этого вывод, вы не верно использовали стиль и когда создавали View не использовался weight 1, и ваша View скорей всего исчезала, после того как вы выставили ей вес через LayoutParams она начала отображаться. Аналоигчно и другим параметрам. Но чтоб такого не происходило, советую прочитать заголовок ответа. Успехов.

Comment: Большое спасибо за качественный ответ, я с ним ознакомился. К сожалению, у меня возникли проблемы с компьютером, и я не могу проверить Ваш метод. В ближайшее время всё же постараюсь это сделать.